# How do I run a command with spaces on the name? The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

These are the questions I used to build these commands:

1. [Assign output of a program to a variable using a MS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-using-a-ms-batch-file)
2. [The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect inside batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782826/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect-inside-batch)
3. [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

If I run the command, by creating a temp file, everything works fine:

```
"%CYGWIN_ROOT%bin\cygpath.exe" -u "%InstallImprovedSettings%" > motherfockingtemp.txt
set /p InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=<motherfockingtemp.txt
"%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\rm" -fv motherfockingtemp.txt
```

But, creating a file to assign a variable is too much overkill. If I try to do so, without creating temporary and silly files as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`'%CYGWIN_ROOT%bin\cygpath.exe' -u "%InstallImprovedSettings%"`) do (
SET "InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=%%F"
)
```

Batch gives the error:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %g IN (`'C:\CygwinPortable\Cyg  win\bin\cygpath.exe' -u "C:\CygwinPortable\Cyg  win\cygwin-install-improved-settings.sh"`) do (SET "InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=%F" )
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

And if I replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %g IN (`"C:\CygwinPortable\Cyg  win\bin\cygpath.exe" -u "C:\CygwinPortable\Cyg  win\\cygwin-install-improved-settings.sh"`) do (SET "InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=%F" )
'C:\CygwinPortable\Cyg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I use commands with spaces on their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use single-quotes to just enclose the command itself; either use single-quotes to enclose the *whole* command line including all the arguments, or, when using the `usebackq` option, use back-ticks instead.

The last attempt of yours complies with that (here once again but with the correct `for` meta-variable used in the loop body):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('"%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\cygpath.exe" -u "%InstallImprovedSettings%"') do (set "InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=%%g")
```

But this still fails, because [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) executes the `cygpath.exe` command line in a new Command Prompt instance by [`cmd /c`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), which strips the first and last quotation marks and leaves the following invalid command line behind:

```cmd
%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\cygpath.exe" -u "%InstallImprovedSettings%
```

To prevent this behaviour, just place an additional pair of quotation marks; it is a good idea to [escape](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) them in order not to have to change any other potential escaping:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('^""%CYGWIN_ROOT%\bin\cygpath.exe" -u "%InstallImprovedSettings%"^"') do (set "InstallImprovedSettingsUnix=%%g")
```