# "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error occurs in specific circumstance

Tags: batch-file, cmd, conemu

This is a batch script ***activate.bat*** from the project [w64devkit v1.3.1](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit/releases/tag/v1.3.1)

```
@set PATH=%~dp0\bin;%PATH%
@busybox sh -l
```

I get error "*The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*" when i double click the batch script to run it but when i execute the batch script in the ConEmu terminal, it runs fine and drops me into a busybox shell.

I have read the question and best answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782826/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect-inside-batch) link and i still could not fix the error.

*busybox.exe* is in the bin directory and the *activate.bat* file is one directory above the bin folder.
All these files are in the w64devkit folder which was extracted from the zip file [w64devkit.zip](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit/releases/download/v1.3.1/w64devkit-1.3.1.zip).

My operating system is Windows 8.1 Pro.

@NekoMusume comment worked.
The batch script worked when executed with administrator privileges.

Comment: When you added quotes as per the link in your question, did you use `"%~dp0\bin";%PATH%` or `"%~dp0\bin;%PATH%"`? You need to use the first one.

Comment: Try running as an administrator?

Comment: @NekoMusume solution worked.The batch script worked when ran as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the file as an administrator. Sometimes depending on security policies and group policies administrator access is required when changing environment variables.